# Does anyone else feel unmotivated to work anything due to generally low salaries?

Tags: salary, motivation

I mean, how am I supposed to be motivated to work if 65%, yes 65% of my salary goes just to pay the rent. And that is for a flat of 19 m2, more like a room, not a flat. I can't even buy enough food in the local supermarket to eat as much as I'd like, and not mention other things. And guys this is a local "norm", not just me underpaid, for a work of "junior advisor" to some of Fortune500 companies.

I live in Europe, with a "wrong" passport and can't emigrate easily. I hate the employers with a passion, and just seeing even a 1% of my value added going into their filthy pockets fills me with rage.
Here everyone is complaining, junior analysts are complaining, shop owners are complaining, senior consultants are complaining, and heck even partners in small firms are complaining that they can't afford a 2-bedroom flat and 1 vacation per year. Politicians and "investors" however, have no problem sporting SUVs.

Total misery, despite having 2 master degrees from prestigeous schools. I sometimes contemplate to take them both and shit on them in front of the local city house.

I saw an interesting offer, a local bank is giving away 150$ vouchers if I open an account with them, however the caveat is to have 3000$ to deposit just for a day in order to get the promo coupon. And I don't have that money. In fact, I have only 200$ left in my account. The rich becomes richer, and the poor becomes poorer. I was looking forward to getting the voucher and buying a coffee machine for my 19 m2 home, so at least I can have a cup of coffee in the morning, but what a bummer.

Should I mention that you can't start any business with no cash, even a worthless shitty and miserable web startup in the sea of equally worthless innovations of the "new economy"?

Comment: This is more of a rant than a question. What are you trying to ask here?

Comment: Hi user, we're not a forum for discussion or for venting. We're a Q&A site. The best questions have an objective, fair, impartial tone. Please see [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for more details.

Comment: Chan-chan-chan-chan-changeeees

Comment: #socialismWorks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is "does anyone else feel the same?" then the answer is certainly Yes - surely some others in the world feel the same way.

On the other hand I don't believe most feel this way. In many parts of the world life is far worse. In some parts of the world life is better.

You seem to mostly be feeling bad for yourself. That happens to everyone from time to time.

What will define you as a person is - now what are you going to do about it? Life often isn't easy. Everyone has a "situation". But you have to deal with your own reality, decide where you want to go with it, then take whatever steps you must to get there.

Or you can just decide to feel bad about your life. The choice is yours to make.

Comment: Joe, I think you summed up what I probably failed to get across.  good answer.

Comment: I will also point out that if you are doing a lousy job for the low salary, no one will consider moving you up to a better job anmd salary. That should be motivation enough to do your job well.

Comment: Even guys with 300+k$ salaries are filling for bankruptcies... http://www.nytimes.com/2014/01/25/business/partner-in-a-prestigious-law-firm-and-bankrupt.html?_r=0

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a rant but a couple things here you should consider.

First, salary, like the price of most things, is based on supply and demand.  It sounds like your profession is over supplied, at least in that part of the world.  Which means you have two options.  Either relocate to somewhere else or figure out how to do something else.  This has nothing at all to do with politicians, investors or business owners and everything to do with the number of people willing to work the same job you are for those pay rates.  Having a master's degree is meaningless if everyone has the same one.  There are people in my country with master's degrees working as an assistant at local fast food places simply because those degrees are over supplied.

Next, and this will sting a bit, you have what's called a "first world problem".  There are a few billion people on this planet who struggle just to get food and water.  You are struggling with getting a coffee pot.  Get some perspective.

Finally, I'm not European so I'm not sure what a "wrong" passport is or what "easily" means with regards to emigration.  However it sounds like you need to take a hard look at where you are going and decide if spending the time to fix those two items is worth it.  It might be.

Comment: Assuming by "the wrong passport" he means he is not a citizen of one of the EU member countries and thus cannot freely move and live and work in other EU countries.

Comment: desperate jobseekers, new economy, huh.